# Docker Desktop not starts

Tags: docker

Docker desktop application does not start anymore on my Windows PC. Docker Desktop application is trying to start for very long period. Finaly I'm getting message: `Docker Desktop stopped...`

How to fix this?

Docker log file:

```
[2022-05-20T14:56:45.821144200Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (0f4412ae) ae4e5818-ServiceAPI S<-C eaac4148-ServiceAPIClient-CSharp POST /dns/refresh-hosts
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.<UpdateHostsAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\ServiceAPIClient.cs:line 0
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.UpdateHostsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 101
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<SendState>d__35.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 353
[2022-05-20T14:56:45.874145000Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (0f4412ae) ae4e5818-ServiceAPI S->C eaac4148-ServiceAPIClient-CSharp POST /dns/refresh-hosts (53ms): OK
[2022-05-20T14:59:08.937512300Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (41ce78c0) ae4e5818-ServiceAPI S<-C 08136780-ServiceAPIClient-CSharp POST /windowsfeatures/check
   at Docker.Core.HttpClientExtensions.<PostJsonWithJsonResponseAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\HttpClientExtensions.cs:line 22
   at Docker.Core.HttpClientExtensions.PostJsonWithJsonResponseAsync[T](HttpClient httpClient, String uri, Object content, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.<CheckFeaturesAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\ServiceAPIClient.cs:line 35
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.CheckFeaturesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, WindowsFeature[] windowsFeatures)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoCheckPreconditionsAsync>d__33.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 305
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.DoCheckPreconditionsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 57
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 31
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStopAsync>d__32.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 286
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<SendState>d__35.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 353
[2022-05-20T14:59:08.937512300Z][Installer         ][Info   ] Checking for features: VirtualMachinePlatform, Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
[2022-05-20T14:59:09.772765500Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (41ce78c0) ae4e5818-ServiceAPI S->C 08136780-ServiceAPIClient-CSharp POST /windowsfeatures/check (835ms): OK
[2022-05-20T14:59:10.374909000Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (ad841311) ae4e5818-ServiceAPI S<-C 9f7328f6-ServiceAPIClient-CSharp POST /dns/refresh-hosts
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.<UpdateHostsAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\ServiceAPIClient.cs:line 0
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.UpdateHostsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 101
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<SendState>d__35.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 353
[2022-05-20T14:59:10.428909900Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (ad841311) ae4e5818-ServiceAPI S->C 9f7328f6-ServiceAPIClient-CSharp POST /dns/refresh-hosts (53ms): OK
```

Content of `.wslconfig` file:

```
[wsl2]
memory=10GB
swap=0
```

If I remove `.wslconfig` file I will get error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
distro stopped unexpectedly
   at Docker.Engines.LinuxkitDaemonStartup.<WaitAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\LinuxkitDaemonStartup.cs:line 60
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 177
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 69
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<RestartAsync>d__27.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 275
```

Comment: Do you have hardware virtualization enabled?  Have you tried to reinstall Docker Desktop? Does the WSL2 Linux instance run by itself? Are you building Docker yourself from source? The path is extremely odd.

Comment: I have installed Docker Desktop from official site. Path `C:\workspaces\PR-17739\` looks odd. I have no idea why I have this path in log file

Comment: It’s looks like you pulled the GitHub a specific Pull Request from the GitHub repository for Docker

Comment: I have reinstalled Docker Desktop, but still have the same problem